# How pickers should behave

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

My app has a picker view. Right now I have it set to dismiss when the user clicks outside of it. This took a lot of hackery to do.

My question is, what is default behavior for a picker view? When should it dismiss? Is there any problem with the way I'm doing it? The documentation doesn't seem to say much about how pickerviews should be dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Thats all about you. Some apps have a picker that you can't dismiss at all, others have dismissable pickers.

I'd say:

• If your picker is in the way (hides other objects) then it should be dismissable, preferably by touching the background and by a button that shows up together with your picker and dismisses with your picker.

• If you design your app so that the picker fits, and doesn't hide any objects, then you can leave it there.